# Is $(7,4)$ the only non-trivial integer solution for $(n)_k=n!$?

Tags: combinatorics, diophantine-equations, factorial, gamma-function, pochhammer-symbol

I accidentally noticed that:

$$(7)_4=7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 \cdot 10=2 \cdot  3 \cdot  4 \cdot  5 \cdot  6 \cdot  7=7!$$

Here  $(n)_k$ is the Pochhammer symbol.

> I wonder, are there any other non-trivial integer solutions $(n,k)$?
>
> $$(n)_k=n!$$

Among the ones I consider trivial we have $(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(2,1)$. Somehow, I'm sure that I will get a lot of comments with these four solutions.

This is the implicit plot of the equivalent equation:

$$\Gamma (n+k)=n \Gamma^2 (n)$$

[image]

Comment: Nice question...

Comment: I wish you the best of luck on this one.

Comment: @Axoren, is the problem unsolved? If it is, I'm sure there are reasons...

Comment: I think that the answer (no) lies in the fact that there is no number larger than $10$ which can be "split" into two parts containing the same prime factors, i.e., there will always be a prime factor which is present in one of the parts but not in the other. In your example, $10$ is "split" into $[1-7]$ and $[7-10]$, both parts containing the same prime factors (and **even** with the same multiplicity for each factor).

Comment: You can easily prove that, if $n>1$, then $n$ must be prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n+k\geq 14$, then there are at two primes in the interval $\left(\frac{n+k-1}{2},n+k-1\right]$.  Therefore, $(n+k-1)!$ cannot equal $n\cdot \big((n-1)!\big)^2$.  This leaves the cases $n+k\leq 13$ to be dealt with.

Comment: I don't see the justification for the "*therefore*". If $k < n - 1$ then $n-1 \in \left(\frac{n+k-1}{2},n+k-1\right]$, so what's the obstacle?

Comment: Well, the primes in this interval must be factors of $n$, but then their product is greater than $n+k-1$.

Comment: Why must they be factors of $n$? Why can't they be $n-1$ and $n-3$?

Comment: Because each of them occurs with multiplicity $1$ in $(n+k-1)!$.